# Upgrading Global Ruby Version on macOS

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm, rbenv

I am trying to update Ruby on my computer to version 2.7.0 as that is the latest stable version.

Running macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3

Have tried the top two solutions from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485180/how-to-update-ruby-with-homebrew) post.

**1. Using just brew**

`brew upgrade ruby`

just confirms that "ruby 2.6.5 already installed"

**2. Using rbenv**

`rbenv install 2.7.0`

`rbenv global 2.7.0`

After installation I get confirmation that ruby 2.7.0 is installed, but when I close terminal, and check version, 2.6.5 is still the current version.

Initially when I tried this, I got an error `BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.3 using ruby-build 20200115)`. Based on advise in [this github issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/910) I found that Xcode was not installed (it was installed, but something removed it in the last few months). I re-installed it, but still got the same issue.

**3. Also tried RVM based on answer 3 from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574318/how-do-i-upgrade-my-ruby-1-9-2-p0-to-the-latest-patch-level-using-rvm).**

`rvm upgrade 2.7.0`

But I am prompted if I want to use ruby-2.6.3
I did said yes by accident. So now I am back down to 2.6.3

Do I need to do something more to change the global environment settings for Ruby? It seemed that `rbenv global 2.7.0` would do this.

Comment: I don't recommend brew's version or rbenv. (though many people swear by rbenv) If you remove both of those and have only RVM installed, then you can `rvm install 2.7.0` and then `rvm --default use 2.7.0` and it'll stick.

Comment: How would I remove the brew version and the rbenv version?

Comment: `brew uninstall ruby` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840977/3784008

Comment: That worked, but I still need to type `rvm --default use 2.7.0` every time I start a new terminal. Is there a way to permanently make it default?

Comment: Run the `--default` command, then run `rvm list`, then exit your terminal and open it again, then run `rvm list` again. Paste the output of `rvm list` into your question for us to see both before and after.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per advice from *anothermh*, uninstalled rbenv and brew versions of Ruby

**Uninstallation**

`brew uninstall ruby` for removing brew version

Use accepted answer on [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173968/how-do-you-uninstall-rbenv-on-osx/36840977#36840977) for removing rbenv

**Install Ruby via RVM**

Install RVM [as per instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) || [as per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677771/rvm-command-not-found-mac-ox#answer-62365786)

`rvm install (ruby version)`

`rvm --default use (ruby version)`

can use `rvm list` to see available ruby versions.

Comment: How to install `rvm`?

Comment: @Machado Included link to the RVM installation guide on their website

Comment: Why remove `rbenv`? Is it just an example or there are some reasons to prefer `rvm`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have rbenv, run these commands in Terminal:

1. `rbenv install 3.0.1`(or any other desired version number) to install the version you want.
2. `rbenv versions`, to verify that the newly installed version is on the list.
3. `rbenv global` to see which version is set to be your global version.
4. `rbenv global 3.0.1` to make this (i.e. 3.0.1) version global.
5. `rbenv global` command to verify which is your global version, it should now be 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using Homebrew to update Ruby because it can create problems with the OS. A very complete and safe explanation I found is at this medium post https://ashley-tharp.medium.com/getting-started-with-ruby-on-macos-a4d78e633e11

It worked very well for me. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I my case :

```
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
```

Then :

```
brew update
```

Finally :

```
rvm install 2.6.1
```