# Unable to update Ruby on macOS Catalina version 10.15.3

Tags: ruby, macos

macOS comes with pre-installed ruby and its current installed version on my mac is **2.6.3** and I want to update it to **2.7.0**

I have tried multiple methods, but I'm not able to update it. Also, **rvm** isn't installing on my mac.

I have the following things already installed :
1. Xcode CTL
2. Homebrew
3. gcc
4. gnu

Comment: What I did is use `brew` to install `rbenv` and `rbenv` to install newer ruby.

Comment: Apart from that I don't see why this isn't a duplicate, as the question has been asked and answered many times in many ways. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182199/upgrading-global-ruby-version-on-macos is an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading Global Ruby Version on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182199/upgrading-global-ruby-version-on-macos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need add gpg key.

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

Then install rvm via CURL. If you don't have CURL, install it via Homebrew `brew install curl`

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

then `rvm list` to get installed version of ruby.

then `rvm list known` to get the available version.

then `rvm install 2.7.0` to install ruby 2.7.0.

then `rvm --default use 2.7.0` to use it.